# LinqToSQl changing Datasource

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, linq-to-sql, orm

I am working on a web application project where the DAL is generated using LinqToSql designer in Visual Studio. All data access logic is in a separate project.

I created a copy of the database with same structure and same names for tables, views etc. I tried to change the connection string to the new source, but it is not working. Somehow, it still accesses the old database.

All of the following changes failed:

- Changed the connection string in config files for all the projects in the solution which is now pointing to new data source.
- Create a partial class for the DataContext and passed new connection string to the constructor after changing the connection string to "none" in Visual Studio LinqToSql designer properties.
- Passed the connection string explicitly whenever I instantiated the DataContext.
- Deleted the contents of bin and obj folders for the LinqToSql project and rebuilt everything.

My project is saving new data to the new datasource, but when reading data it is getting it from the old database, and also throwing null exceptions when it connects to the old DB for data.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any fix for this? What is the best way to make a project with LinqToSql DataContext point to a new datasource with the same data (for example: dev, staging, release, etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: Have you done a solution-wide Find for the connection string? Might be lingering somewhere you don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading data from the old database, there must be a connect string or similar in your project that hasn't been updated.

There are three places where the LINQ to SQL designer might be storing the old connection information:

- In the app.config file.
- In the Settings.settings file.
- In the default constructor for the DataContext.

Check all of them.

You could also use 'Find' to search your entire solution for any other references to the old database hard-coded into your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked all the three and all of them are pointing to new datasource.

Comment: @Flowerking: Then 'Find in all files' is your best bet. If that doesn't find anything then your source and binaries may be out-of-sync.

Comment: I tried finding references in entire solution which is only pointing to commented out connection strings in config file. May be its the problem with binaries as you suggested.